# How to get two results as single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, merge

I have two result sets as [image]
I want both results as a single table with two columns(education,schools). Can I use any temp tables or is there any easy way??
Thank you

edited
[image]

Comment: sorry ..you misunderstood my requirement?? I want a table with two columns

Comment: How many rows should your output have? There is no logical link between the two outputs when you combine them, i.e. it is no more correct to have `|MCA | SGSITS INDORE|`, than it is to have `|MCA | MP BOARD BHOPAL|`. With no logical relationship you would have  Cartesian product, so end up with (in this case) 16 rows.

Comment: Is it posible if I have a relation in both the results ? Check my edited image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relation to use then you can just join the tables as normal:

```
WITH Eduction AS
(   SELECT  item,
            ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Item)
    FROM    fnSplit((SELECT DegreeType FROM HR_EmpEducation WHERE EmpID = 9), '|')
), Schools AS
(   SELECT  item,
            ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Item)
    FROM    fnSplit((SELECT School_Inst FROM HR_EmpEducation WHERE EmpID = 9), '|')
)   
SELECT  Eduration = ISNULL(e.Item, ''),
        Schools = ISNULL(s.Item, '')
FROM    Education e
        FULL JOIN Schools s
            ON e.ID = s.ID;
```

I have used a FULL JOIN to account for one split function having more results than the other.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to do combine the records, since an individual record in your source table might have a varying number of degrees and institutions.  The resulting table won't make sense.

Just leave the information in separate tables.  To relate these tables to each other, make each original query also get identifying information (such as an individual's ID).  You will then be able to use this information to link back to the individual the data represents.